# Is there a way to have a CSS selector apply to a specific host? (For my custom browser stylesheet.)

Tags: css, webkit

I want to apply styles (**edit:in my browser's user-defined stylesheet, a local file on my machine that let's me customize how other people's websites render for me**) to a specific site, but the selectors on many web pages are often generic (and obviously out of my control, since they're not my websites.)

If I have to use very general selectors (eg. #box) to customize a given website, that style might unintentionally affect other websites that have that same generic selector. Is there a way to specify a domain with a selector so I can my custom styles for each website separate?

I also found [@-moz-document](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum119/453.htm) which looks good, but is Mozilla-specific and I use a WebKit browser. Is there an equivalent?

```
@-moz-document url(https://www.example.com/decrypt.php) {
```

Comment: (This was originally an answer but I made it a comment with some extra info.) As far as I know, the `document` directive is a Mozilla extension and as such is not found in WebKit (or any other engines). [There's now a proposal for a `@document` rule in CSS3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-conditional/#at-document), based on Gecko's implementation, but Gecko is still the only engine to implement it right now.

Comment: Generic `@document` is postponed until CSS4, but we may see `@-<x>-document` variants in the meantime, I have no idea about specific engines' progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the CSS hosted on a server that also allows you to script? Have you tried writing a server-side script to generate the correct CSS rules depending on the host that's serving the page?

*Edit added March 30 2010:*

You might be better off using the Greasemonkey extension to do this. It's far more powerful than user-defined stylesheets since you can use JavaScript, and adding domain or page-specific rules is as easy as adding special tags to the comments in the header. Greasemonkey was made specifically for handling your type of problem, and while you need a plugin to run Greasemonkey scripts in Firefox, Chrome ships with Greasemonkey support built-in.

Comment: This isn't server-side, it's a local file that my browser uses to override the behavior on the pages I browse.

Comment: You might be better off using the Greasemonkey extension to do this. It's far more powerful than user-defined stylesheets since you can use JavaScript, and adding domain or page-specific rules is as easy as adding special tags to the comments in the header. 

Greasemonkey was made specifically for handling your type of problem, and while you need a plugin to run Greasemonkey scripts in Firefox, Chrome ships with Greasemonkey support built-in.

Comment: I prefer Safari, so I'd use a Safari Extension, but I think you're correct -- there's no way around it with CSS. If you want to edit your comment into your answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Done. I believe this might be the extension for Safari: http://8-p.info/greasekit/

Comment: Yes, a userscript is certainly the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the HTML using javascript, there would be a way.  It could go something like this (using JQuery):

```
var hostId = // detect the id of the host
var highLevelElement = $("body");  // or a different element that holds everything
highLevelElement.attr("id", hostId);
```

Then, in your CSS, you can do this:

```
#Mozilla div.Whatever { background-color: orange; }
#IE6 div.Whatever { background-color: red; }
#IE9 div.Whatever { background-color: green; }
// etc.
```

Comment: That's have to be a a browser extension because it uses Javascript, which I'm hoping to avoid.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Notice the edit history of the post and the time that this answer was posted.  The information causing you to dislike this answer wasn't available at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Consider installing an ad blocker such as uBlockOrigin, then writing some custom filters. You can add these custom filters in Settings -> My Filters.

```
examplewebsite.com###ExampleId, .ExampleClass:style(background-color: yellow !important;)
```

Answer (score -4):

Uhm, I think php would be the most rational solution, and actually very easy.
Use php to decide what/when to do and echo certain css files in certain cases.

If you need more help, tell us more about your problem and I'll write the complete solution for you.

Comment: Pretty sure PHP can't help me here. I'm trying to set this in my browser's custom stylesheet. This isn't server-side code, but thanks for the offer.